# The "Multiple files found for the same tablespace ID" error inside a docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I have the next docker-compose.yaml config:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    platform: linux/x86_64
    image: mysql:8.0-debian
    ports:
      - ${DOCKER_DB_PORT}:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DOCKER_DB_DATABASE:?err}
      MYSQL_USER: ${DOCKER_DB_USER:?err}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DOCKER_DB_PASSWORD:?err}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DOCKER_DB_ROT_PASSWORD:?err}
    volumes:
      - ../db-volume-stage:/var/lib/mysql
```

In the `../db-volume-stage` directory is mysql files which were unzip from the archive, which was made based on the same volume on my local machine. So locally on my machine it works good.

But when I run `docker-compose up db` on another machine, the container prints me the next error and dies:

```
Starting stage_db_1 ... done
Attaching to stage_db_1
db_1     | 2024-01-01 08:40:08+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.35-1debian11 started.
db_1     | 2024-01-01 08:40:08+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
db_1     | 2024-01-01 08:40:08+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.35-1debian11 started.
db_1     | 2024-01-01T08:40:09.030311Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
db_1     | 2024-01-01T08:40:09.030518Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.35) starting as process 1
db_1     | 2024-01-01T08:40:09.042705Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
db_1     | 2024-01-01T08:40:09.298927Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012209] [InnoDB] Multiple files found for the same tablespace ID:
db_1     | 2024-01-01T08:40:09.299035Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012202] [InnoDB] Tablespace ID: 1 = ['db-volume/mysite/goods_files.ibd', 'mysite/goods_files.ibd'] 

# Here there are the same records for all other tables

db_1     | 2024-01-01T08:41:58.747985Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Failed, retry may succeed.
db_1     | 2024-01-01T08:41:58.748023Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
db_1     | 2024-01-01T08:41:58.748211Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
db_1     | 2024-01-01T08:41:58.748227Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
db_1     | 2024-01-01T08:41:58.748721Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.35)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
stage_db_1 exited with code 1
```

I'm confused with the next thing:In the log I can see the next path to the file: `db-volume/mysite/goods_files.ibd`, but in reality my files are in the `db-volume-stage` directory, `db-volume` - is a name of the directory on my local computer.

What can course that error?